# What to do with old questions that are examples of what not to do?

Tags: discussion, questions, equipment-recommendations

While browsing around today, I found [What are the pros/cons of a Canon SX30IS compared to Fuji HS 10 / HS 20?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6908/what-are-the-pros-cons-of-a-canon-sx30is-compared-to-fuji-hs-10-hs-20), a three year old question which to me looks like a question that is a bad question for all the reasons we now say: it's no longer useful as neither the SX30 nor the HS20 are still available, and it's attracted a number of  the "XYZ is great" answers without any reasoning.

What's the best thing to do with this sort of question (I'm sure there's a number of them out there)? If it were raised today, we'd probably close it pretty sharpishly as "product or equipment recommendation". That's probably still a sensible thing to do with old questions, but is there anything else we should do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's truly a bad example for the site, flag for a moderator to potentially lock it as historically interesting, but not a good example of a good question. There's been a few that I've locked for this reason before.

Comment: For this one, my personal opinion leans towards "not even historically interesting"....

Comment: @mattdm - yeah, very true... That lock takes it out of the question list though, so only can be found with a search.